# File input doesn't open SO selection box [Angular]

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular project and I don't have experience with the framework. I'm trying to add an input to upload a file and I wrote a simple `<input type="file" (change)="function()" />`. I see the input on the page but when I click the button to select the file nothing happens, not even a message on console.

I tried to create a component only for this upload and I add a form around the input, but the result was the same. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you try to print the `$event` from the `function`? (`<input type="file" (change)="function($event)"/>`)

Comment: Yes, I have the $event. I should put this. What I saying is that the button act like it has no function. I expect to open the windows explorer to select something, but it doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the event file from the input, like this:

```
  <input id="file" type="file" (change)="function($event.target.files)">
```

And in the component:

```
function(files) {
    // Rest of the logic
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the $event. I should put this. What I saying is that the button act like it has no function. I expect to open the windows explorer to select something, but it doesn't happen

Comment: Which angular version are you using?. What operating system?. Please put a more detailed code. Also check your extensions to see if something is intercepting the button (did you try to test it on an incognito window?). Also, it might sound dumb, but did you try to close the browser completely and open it again?

Comment: Hi Alejandro, I didn't answer before because I was working in something else. But now I'm working in this upload again. The Angular version is 10.2.3 and I using Windows 10. I tried in incognito window and happened the same.

I will update my question with more code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was blocking the input. The project uses Angular Material, and is using Sidenav component. Someone add a click event capture inside `<mat-sidenav-component>` and that was the problem.